# Altium Designer - Selecting multiple designators in SCH and moving causes an error

Tags: altium

When I select multiple designators in the SCH and try to move them via mouse cursor, the designators suddenly shifts to the right, and my cursor teleports to the bottom left of the screen. However I can move individual designators and multiple components just fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: What version Altium? I am seeing a bunch of glitchy mouse movement in Altium 17, but not this particular issue. In the past I've been told this is a display driver issue (why a display driver affects the mouse I dunno)...but I never got to the bottom of it.

Comment: I am using 17.1.6

Comment: @ThePhoton I ended up having to replace my video card because of weirdness in v17. Blurry pin net markings.. sad.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, Unfortunately for me, that's not so easy to do when your work-issued PC is a laptop.